# Objective C: Good way to define C array like MyStruct theArray[18][18]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to use something like a C array:

```
MyStruct theArray[18][18];
```

but I cannot define it as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) MyStruct theArray[18][18];
```

then I have to:

```
@implementation MyClass
{
    MyStruct theArray[18][18];
}
```

But is this good in term of modern Objective C guideline?

Thanks

Update:

I know I can define the struct as class and use NSMutableArray to handle it, but it is more convenient to use the C array in my case, the main concern is coding guideline and memory issue, as I do not allocate or release the theArray[18][18], not sure what its life cycle is, and I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties cannot be of array type, while public instance variables do not provide sufficient encapsulation. A more Objective C - like approach would be defining a private 2D array, and a pair of methods or a method returning a pointer to access it - something along these lines:

```
// For small structs you can use a pair of methods:
-(MyStruct)getElementAtIndexes:(NSUInteger)i and:(NSUInteger)j;
-(void)setElementAtIndexes:(NSUInteger)i and:(NSUInteger)j to:(MyStruct)val;

// For larger structs you should use a single method that returns a pointer
// to avoid copying too much data:
-(MyStruct*)elementAtIndexes:(NSUInteger)i and:(NSUInteger)j;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about use pointers instead?

```
@property (nonatomic) MyStruct **theArray;
```

Comment: Then I need to use malloc to allocate memory? Is this a bit non-ObjC?

Comment: If you're going to use C-arrays, that's not exactly objective-c right? I would say this is the most painless way in your case, though you will have to (as you said) use `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far are great. . . here's two more options:

**1. A bit hacky**

(I'm not sure if this requires Objective-C++)

You can create the array as a public property like so:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    @public:
    MyStruct theArray[18][18];
}
@end
```

And then access it as follows:

```
myClass->theArray
```

***2. Return a Struct***

While you can't return a C-style array, you can return a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
     CGPoint textureCoordinates[kMaxHillVertices];
     CGPoint borderVertices[kMaxBorderVertices];
} HillsDrawData;


@interface Hills : NSObject
{
    HillsDrawData _drawData;
}


- (HillsDrawData)drawData; //This will get cleaned up when the class that owns it does.

@end
```